# Removing childnodes using HAP

Tags: windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

When i'm trying to remove a childnode from my xpath i'm getting a weird error:-

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Node "" was not found in the collection

I know there an issue with HAP childremoving but idk if they have fix it with the new release or not. My question is it my code that is wrong or is it HAP? In either way is there any way to get around that and remove those childnode?

Here is my code:-

```
        List<MediNetScheme> medinetScheme = new List<MediNetScheme>();
        HtmlDocument htdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htdoc.LoadHtml(results);
        foreach (HtmlNode table in htdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]"))
        {
            string itemValue = string.Empty;
            HtmlNode ansvarig =table.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]/td[4]");
            table.RemoveChild(ansvarig, true);
            itemValue = table.InnerText;
            medinetScheme.Add(new MediNetScheme(){Datum=itemValue.Remove(15),Sections=itemValue.Remove(0,15)});
        }
        MediNetScheme.ItemsSource = medinetScheme;
```

Edit:-

My HTML document has a table with several rows that have this xpath :- "//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEZif.jpg)/tr[@class]". Each row in this table have 5 columns td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEZif.jpg)...td[5]. In my first foreach loop i'm using selectnodes to get the HTMLcode of each row in the table. What i want to do is to get only the innertext from the first 3 td in each row, which means i need to get rid of td[4] and td[5] from each row. When i used your edited code, i was able to get rid of td[4] and td[5] in the first row but not other rows that follows the first row.

Here is a pic of my HTML:-
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of testing different codes and ways to achive what i wanted, i figured it out.

But i have to thank vfportero for his answer and flag it as answer too.

The answer to the edited verion of my question is simply this code ;)

```
List<MediNetScheme> medinetScheme = new List<MediNetScheme>();
        HtmlDocument htdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htdoc.LoadHtml(results);
        foreach (HtmlNode table in htdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]"))
        {
            table.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(3);
            string itemValue = table.InnerText;
            medinetScheme.Add(new MediNetScheme(){Datum=itemValue.Remove(15),Sections=itemValue.Remove(0,15)}); 
        }
        MediNetScheme.ItemsSource = medinetScheme;
```

You can see that i omit RemoveChild method coz it was not doing what i wanted (plz read the edit of my question), and instead i used .ChildNodes.RemoveAt(int //the placeof the child you want to remove).
Hope this will help some other ppl facing the same problem.

Yours

Comment: Thanks for your flag :) I'm glad you has encountered a nice solution

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

the better way to remove a node from their parent in `HtmlAgilityPack` is this:

```
nodeToRemove.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
```

In your code you can use like this:

```
List<MediNetScheme> medinetScheme = new List<MediNetScheme>();
HtmlDocument htdoc = new HtmlDocument();
htdoc.LoadHtml(results);
foreach (HtmlNode table in htdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]"))
{
    string itemValue = string.Empty;
    HtmlNode ansvarig =table.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]/td[4]");
    ansvarig.ParentNode.RemoveChild(ansvarig);
    itemValue = table.InnerText;
    medinetScheme.Add(new MediNetScheme(){Datum=itemValue.Remove(15),Sections=itemValue.Remove(0,15)});
 }
 MediNetScheme.ItemsSource = medinetScheme;
```

I hope this will be useful for you :)

EDITED:
Do you want to get the InnerText of the three first td's in each row.
I'm checking your code and i think that xpath inside the foreach is wrong.

I would change the xpath for a classic counted loop with linq like this:

```
foreach (HtmlNode trNodes in htdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]"))
{
    string itemValue = string.Empty;
    int position = 1;
    foreach (var td in tr.DescendantNodes("td"))
    {
        itemValue = td .InnerText;
        medinetScheme.Add(new MediNetScheme(){Datum=itemValue.Remove(15),Sections=itemValue.Remove(0,15)});
        position++;
        if (position == 3)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks vfportero! unfortunately even your method is not working like i want, tho i'm not getting this exception error. However the problem now is that it is removing the childnode from only the first node in "table" and not from the subsequent other nodes.

Comment: What exactly do you want? "ansvarig" is a 'td' cell and the "RemoveChild" are deleting this td fron this tr parent. Do you want to remove all td's in that tr? Can you post a example html to ilustrate better your question?

Comment: I have updated the question for better illustration of the problem.